# R Quantmod chartSeries() error

Tags: r, quantmod

I encountered the following error when I tried to execute `chartSeries` on a daily forex data.

I think the csv dataset should be in order with no missing fields or invalid data in between

A sample of the csv data which was successfully executed with getSymbols()

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adjusted
2005-06-13,1.0796,1.0812,1.0749,1.0791,9456,0
2005-06-14,1.0792,1.0806,1.0784,1.0793,11229,0
2005-06-15,1.0791,1.0799,1.0775,1.0783,9861,0
2005-06-16,1.0785,1.0820,1.0776,1.0813,10687,0
2005-06-17,1.0815,1.0863,1.0796,1.0843,8829,0
2005-06-20,1.0842,1.0864,1.0823,1.0850,8391,0
2005-06-21,1.0853,1.0891,1.0836,1.0879,9864,0

chartSeries(AUDNZD,type="candlestick")

Error :
Error in if(on=="years") {:missing values where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have even added the following options

```
chartSeries(AUDNZD,type="candlestick",**subset="null",bar.type="olhc", major.ticks="day",plot="true"**)
```

to the chartSeries() ,the error then becomes

```
Error in if (length(c(year,month,day, hour,min,sec))==6 && c(year,:missing values where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

look as if  the time series may be the cause of the error afterall , chartSeries function was somehow trying to determine the correct timeseries scale to apply , the date field was orignially formatted in the string format "yyyy-mm-dd", no idea if this was the correct format or not?

Could anyone help me to resolve the issues please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
> aud <- read.csv("c:\\aud.csv")
> aud
        Date   Open   High    Low  Close Volume Adjusted
1 2005-06-13 1.0796 1.0812 1.0749 1.0791   9456        0
2 2005-06-14 1.0792 1.0806 1.0784 1.0793  11229        0
3 2005-06-15 1.0791 1.0799 1.0775 1.0783   9861        0
4 2005-06-16 1.0785 1.0820 1.0776 1.0813  10687        0
5 2005-06-17 1.0815 1.0863 1.0796 1.0843   8829        0
6 2005-06-20 1.0842 1.0864 1.0823 1.0850   8391        0
7 2005-06-21 1.0853 1.0891 1.0836 1.0879   9864        0
> aud.xts <- as.xts(zoo(aud[,2:6],order.by=as.Date(aud$Date)))
> chart_Series(aud.xts)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Haki , Thanks ,when i execute your suggestion , i only got white background , if i change to chartSeries , a black theme appearing , if there a way to set the candlestick into color mode?

Comment: `chartSeries` is the old version of `quantmod`. I personally use the new version which is `chart_Series`. You can change the theme of the graph - read the [docs](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantmod/quantmod.pdf). If i'm not mistaking there is an open bug about changing the background color with a user defined theme in `chart_Series`. other then that ....

Comment: Hello Haki, Thanks, I manage to create a theme using chartTheme() , I am putting the whole statement for the benefit of the community AUD<-read.csv("c:/misc/AUDNZD.csv")
AUD.xts<-as.xts(zoo(AUD[,2:7],order.by=as.Date(AUD$Date)))
chartSeries(AUD.xts,type="candlesticks",TA=c(addVo()),plot="TRUE",theme=chartTheme('black',up.col="blue",dn.col='red'),line.type="1",
bar.type="ohlc")